# i can't stream video from http path in flutter video player

Tags: flutter

i'm trying to create new video player app that load vast xml and and extract the data from it.
one item in the data  is video file url path, it can be http or https and i can't know in advance, 
i can't just replace http to https because then it can be wrong domain name.
is there a why to stream the video file with http?
Thaks.